# is this command secure? exec cat file.txt |jq -r .Something|cut -c 1-21 |xargs

Tags: linux, bash, exec, xargs

Is this command secure?

```
exec cat file.json |jq -r .Something|cut -c 1-21 |xargs
```

You should know that third parties can edit file.json

Comment: I don't see any security problems apart from possible security problems in `cat`, `jq`, `cut`, `xargs`. However, I'm wondering why you wrote `exec cat` instead of just `cat`.

Comment: `|xargs` does nothing more than read the text from the `stdout` of the `cut` command, and display it.  It does not execute the text, so it should be fine.